# Align grid column items (like justify: flex-start)

Tags: css, css-grid

```
<thing>
    <h2 class='heading'>
        HEADING
    </h2>

    <video-thing>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/1600x1100">
    </video-thing>

    <description>
        <p>TEXT</p>

        <button class='unfold'>Read more</button>
    </description>
</thing>
```

This is the the natural order for things in the markup.

[image: small screen layout example]

At some breakpoint, I'm going for this:

[image]

But - I'm still thinking from flex-box world. I want that first 'column' to align flex-start*ish*.

Note how the longer text fills the space in the first item, and the short text in the second example stays to it's 'half.'

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/2ed668cb7f60c6f283b5573492470e11)

I'm guessing that this alignment is the "block axis" re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    thing {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: [message] 1fr [visual] 1fr;
        /* HERE */
    }
    .heading, description {
        grid-column: message;
    }
    video-thing {
        grid-column: visual;
        grid-row: 1/3;
    }
}
```

I also worked with grid-area but came to the same end.

I know this is *totally different* than flex-box / but I'm pretty sure what I'm suggesting is possible - and that I just don't know how to speak 'grid' yet. ; )

[image]

**UPDATE**
@Temani Afif's suggestion has enlightened me - so, here are a few more images to help illustrate it.

[image]

Without explicitly setting a `grid-template-rows` on the parent - it will infer based on whatever grid-row setting you set for the child... so, in this case - there will be a third row created that will 'grow' because they are 'auto' by default / but with just the two - it couldn't. It would also work if you put `1/4` or `span 100` for the record. Or to have explicitly set more rows and with area - or a few other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for this configuration:

```
thing {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:  1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows:auto auto auto; /*not mandatory, you can remove it */
}
video-thing {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: span 3;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* + reset */

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

thing,
video-thing,
description {
  display: block;
}

body {
  /* some context */
  width: 98%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

thing {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 799px) {
  video-thing {
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  thing {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .heading,
  description {
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  description {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  video-thing {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: span 3;
  }
}

thing {
  border: 4px solid green;
}

.heading {
  border: 4px solid orange;
}

description {
  border: 4px solid blue;
}

video-thing {
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.heading {
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Georgia';
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

p+p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

thing+thing {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<thing>
  <h2 class='heading'>Video section / what you should know number 1</h2>

  <video-thing>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1600x1100">
  </video-thing>

  <description>
    <p><strong>Full text description stuff here</strong>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe atque placeat eaque fugiat voluptatibus voluptatum excepturi ut sunt odit voluptates sint cum quasi illo quae laboriosam, reiciendis
      consequatur veniam iusto.</p>
    <p><strong>Full text description stuff here</strong>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe atque placeat eaque fugiat voluptatibus voluptatum excepturi ut sunt odit voluptates sint cum quasi illo quae laboriosam, reiciendis
      consequatur veniam iusto.</p>
    <p><strong>Full text description stuff here</strong>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe atque placeat eaque fugiat voluptatibus voluptatum excepturi ut sunt odit voluptates sint cum quasi illo quae laboriosam, reiciendis
      consequatur veniam iusto.</p>

    <button class='unfold'>Read more</button>
  </description>
</thing>













<thing>
  <h2 class='heading'>Video section / what you should know number 2</h2>

  <video-thing>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1600x1100">
  </video-thing>

  <description>
    <p>short text</p>

    <button class='unfold'>Read more</button>
  </description>
</thing>



<thing>
  <h2 class='heading'>Video section / what you should know number 3</h2>

  <video-thing>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1600x1100">
  </video-thing>

  <description>
    <p><strong>Full text description stuff here</strong>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe atque placeat eaque fugiat voluptatibus voluptatum excepturi ut sunt odit voluptates sint cum quasi illo quae laboriosam, reiciendis
      consequatur veniam iusto.</p>

    <button class='unfold'>Read more</button>
  </description>
</thing>



<thing>
  <h2 class='heading'>Video section / what you should know number 4</h2>

  <video-thing>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1600x1100">
  </video-thing>

  <description>
    <p><strong>Full text description stuff here</strong>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe atque placeat eaque fugiat voluptatibus voluptatum excepturi ut sunt odit voluptates sint cum quasi illo quae laboriosam, reiciendis
      consequatur veniam iusto.</p>

    <button class='unfold'>Read more</button>
  </description>
</thing>



<thing>
  <h2 class='heading'>Video section / what you should know number 5</h2>

  <video-thing>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1600x1100">
  </video-thing>

  <description>
    <p><strong>Full text description stuff here</strong>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe atque placeat eaque fugiat voluptatibus voluptatum excepturi ut sunt odit voluptates sint cum quasi illo quae laboriosam, reiciendis
      consequatur veniam iusto.</p>

    <button class='unfold'>Read more</button>
  </description>
</thing>


<thing>
  <h2 class='heading'>Video section / what you should know number 6</h2>

  <video-thing>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1600x1100">
  </video-thing>

  <description>
    <p><strong>Full text description stuff here</strong>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe atque placeat eaque fugiat voluptatibus voluptatum excepturi ut sunt odit voluptates sint cum quasi illo quae laboriosam, reiciendis
      consequatur veniam iusto.</p>
    <p><strong>Full text description stuff here</strong>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe atque placeat eaque fugiat voluptatibus voluptatum excepturi ut sunt odit voluptates sint cum quasi illo quae laboriosam, reiciendis
      consequatur veniam iusto.</p>

    <p><strong>Full text description stuff here</strong>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe atque placeat eaque fugiat voluptatibus voluptatum excepturi ut sunt odit voluptates sint cum quasi illo quae laboriosam, reiciendis
      consequatur veniam iusto.</p>

    <p><strong>Full text description stuff here</strong>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe atque placeat eaque fugiat voluptatibus voluptatum excepturi ut sunt odit voluptates sint cum quasi illo quae laboriosam, reiciendis
      consequatur veniam iusto.</p>

    <p><strong>Full text description stuff here</strong>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe atque placeat eaque fugiat voluptatibus voluptatum excepturi ut sunt odit voluptates sint cum quasi illo quae laboriosam, reiciendis
      consequatur veniam iusto.</p>

    <p><strong>Full text description stuff here</strong>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe atque placeat eaque fugiat voluptatibus voluptatum excepturi ut sunt odit voluptates sint cum quasi illo quae laboriosam, reiciendis
      consequatur veniam iusto.</p>

    <button class='unfold'>Read more</button>
  </description>
</thing>
```

Comment: Alright... alright... I like this. So - this really just breaks the thing up into so many little rows that they can smash up together... - so, it would be the same if you used `grid-row: 1/7;` or `grid-row: span 100;` - right? - and the number of rows would just be established based on that

Comment: @sheriffderek yes exactly, we call this the implicit grid. If you want to span columns/rows not defined within the explicit grid, new one will be created automatically

Comment: This is huge for my warped mental model on this front. Thank you. I added an image to the question to show your answer. With this understanding - I could have gone about this in a few different ways. Excellent.